# EBADENGINE npm error when initializing firebase functions in flutter app

Tags: flutter, npm, google-cloud-functions

**The problem**:

When I try to initialize the firebase functions in my flutter app using the command `firebase init functions`, I get a EBADENGINE npm error. Here is the full log:

```
? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? JavaScript
? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? Yes
✔  Wrote functions/package.json
✔  Wrote functions/.eslintrc.js
✔  Wrote functions/index.js
✔  Wrote functions/.gitignore
? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '18' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.11.1', npm: '10.2.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

added 590 packages, and audited 591 packages in 32s

67 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...
i  Writing gitignore file to .gitignore...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

**What I have already tried**:

- Uninstalling and redownloading node.js
- Changing the engine version both in package.json and package-lock.json (where the version is 18 and if I try to change it, it returns to 18)
- Searching into all StackOverFlow an answer that worked for me

**File link**:

https://github.com/fscozano/Gym_PT.git

Once you've downloaded the file, you can find the firebase function initialization in the server folder. So, if you want to recreate the working area, you can simply delete everything in the server folder and try to initialize the functions again.

Something makes me think that the problem could be related to my computer (with MacOS Sonoma) instead of my code. For this I tried to uninstall and redownload node.js, so the issue could be somewhere else.

Comment: Can you check the suggestions in this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70269056/18265702). And seems those are just a warning message as I can see `Firebase initialization complete!` seems it's completed are you facing any issues?

Comment: I suppose this is only a warning but I prefer solving it because I don't want it make other problems. However I solved it downgrading the version of node to 18